# How do I put different Immersive policies to different apps via ADB?

Tags: android, adb

So I'm currently using adb command like

```
adb shell settings put global policy_control immersive.full=org.mozilla.firefox,com.nhn.android.band
```

to hide navigation bar and status bar, and it works great. But now I want to use different immersive policy for different apps like immersive.status. For example, when I tried to run code like

```
adb shell settings put global policy_control immersive.status=com.android.chrome
```

it works but cancels the previous code, makes the Firefox stops running in immersive mode. Is there a way to have different policies at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

I just found this [page](http://adbcommand.com/awesome-adb), and now I understand the mechanism of this command: it assigns a key-value string to the policy_control key, that's why it overwrites the previous setting. And the string format is like `<key1>=<value1>:<key2>=<value2>`.
So the correct command should be

```
adb shell settings put global policy_control immersive.status=com.android.chrome,org.mozilla.firefox:immersive.navigation=org.mozilla.firefox
```

if you want chrome to hide only status bar and firefox to hide both status bar and navigatio bar.
I'm not using the immersive.full key because it seems not working properly in such command, so just put the pack name to both status and navigation key.